# How do I generate a list like the one in the example using a non-inclusive range? (Python)

Tags: python, range

My instructions: Develop and test a Python program that calculates the monthly mortgage payments for a given loan amount, term(number of years) and range of interest rates from 3% to 18%. The fundamental formula for determining this is A/D, where A is the original loan amount, and D is the discount factor. The discount factor is calculated as,

```
D = ((1 + r)^(n) – 1)/r(1 + r) ^ n
```

Where n is the number of total payments(12 times the number of years of the loan) and r is the interest rate, expressed in decimal format (e.g.,.05), divided by 12. A monthly payment table should be generated as shows below:

interest rate: 3%. Monthly payment: 1475.61. 
interest rate: 4%. Monthly payment: 1670.95. 
interest rate: 5%. Monthly payment: 1878.88. 
interest rate: 6%. Monthly payment: 2098.43. 
and so on down to 18%.

This is my code so far:

```
#User input is collected
print('enter your loan amount')
a = (int(input('amount')))

print ('enter the number of years of the loan')
n1 = (int(input('amount')))

print ('enter the interest rate in decimal format')
r1 = (float(input('rate')))

#Then do the math
n = n1 * 12

r = r1 / 12




discount_factor = ((1 + r) ** (n) + 1) / r * (1 + r) ** n

monthly_payment =  a / discount_factor
print (monthly_payment)
```

Comment: Just fyi :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
discount_factor = ((1 + r) ** (n) + 1) / r * (1 + r) ** n
```

to

```
discount_factor = ((1 + r) ** (n) + 1) / (r * (1 + r) ** n)
```

Also note that integer division is taking place, ie `1/3 == 0`.

In python 3, float division is the default, you would implement integer division by `1//3`, but in other versions of python, the default is integer division, you can use the following for float division:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Also, note that the following can be done: `1.0/3` -> float division.

**EDIT**:
Didn't see that `r` is a `float`, nonetheless, it's good to note the above, so I'll leave it.

**EDIT 2 (loop example)**:

```
for i in xrange(1,4):
    print i**2

#prints 1,4,9
```

You should check out a basic loops [tutorial](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/loops.html).

Comment: From how the result of `input` is immediately passed to `int` or `float` (so `input` probably returns a string), I'd guess that they're using Python 3, where dividing two integers yields a float.

Comment: Just noticed the error when the answer came back. That sure cleaned it up. Thanks.

Comment: We had the same answers, sorry I did not see your answer before, my internet is a little slow.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac No problem, that happens to me sometimes too.

Comment: @user3051280 No problem.  Since you're new to SO, here check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Good luck!

Comment: thanks everyone. The logic (mainly mine, and not the code is all cleaned up. would I use for __in range(3,19)? Ranges had me a bit confused in class. I understand that is non-inclusive though, so it would stop at 18 and not count the 19, right?

Comment: @user3051280 Yes, it would not include 19, ie it would iterate through `[3,19)`.

Comment: where exactly does it go? I'd rather figure this out myself, so I'm here looking for help and not the code itself. Should I apply that to r? like for r in range(3,19). I saw him do this in class where it printed 3-18% and their respective monthly payments for each line in class, but wouldn't let us see his code. Many thanks!

Comment: @user3051280 If you have the equation that you want, but all you want to do is change `r`, then put the equation in a loop and iterate over the range that you want to, with respect to `r`.

Comment: Would I do that within the calculations or after the equation, is there way to tell it to go back, add 1 to R, and print the results. repeating until r is equal to 18?

Comment: @user3051280 I made an edit with a loop example, and a link.  Additionally, there are plenty of other tutorials online.  You need to know the fundamentals before you can program.  Otherwise, you're going to be copying code without really knowing what it does...

Comment: Duly noted. Time to go back to notes from class.

Getting close. Now running for rate in rage(3,19), but the monthly payment stays the same.